# Ubuntu 18.04 консольный режим

Tags: linux, ubuntu, консоль, gnome

Ubuntu 18.04 начала загружаться в консольном режиме.
Что с этим делать и как вернуться к обычному gnome3?

Comment: Я так понимаю, что во время загрузки меню *grub*, содержащее список возможных загружаемых ОС не появляется?

Comment: Нет, просто слетел gnome и интерфейс автоматически перешел в консольный режим.

Comment: Ну так, на окне логина есть кнопка выбора ДМ. Попробуйте выбрать что-то другое, зайдите и "починяйте примус" :-)

Answer (score 0):

Достаточно было просто переустановить gnome и уже в конце установки графический интерфейс вернулся.